# combine linux `find` and `cp` with output if file is not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, copy, find

Hello stack overflow -

I would like to take an input text file (one line per file to find) to do two things: copy the files that are found to a different directory and provide a message whether the file is not found. The message does not have to exclusively say a file is not found; it can also include the location of files that are found like the output displayed below. I have not been able to combine the two commands below. Is this possible? I am sure there are alternative solutions and am open to those

#will tell you if a file is not found or the location of the file if found:
command:

`for i in $(cat toGet.txt); do find . -name "$i" | grep . || echo "$i - file not found" ; done`

output:

- file1_L001_R*_001.fastq.gz - file not found
- ./file2_S13_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
- ./file2_S13_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
- file3_L001_R*_001.fastq.gz - file not found

#will copy files found to new directory

`for i in $(cat toGet.txt); do find . -name "$i" -exec cp {} /path/to/directory \; ; done`

Any suggestions

Comment: `for i in $(cat toGet.txt);` will not work if any of the filenames have spaces in their names.

Comment: thank you; I am not worried about spaces as no filenames have spaces in them

Comment: It's a good habit to protect against it, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Write a script that receives the filename to copy on its standard input. If the input is empty, it reports that the file is not found, otherwise it copies it. Then pipe the `find` output to it.

copy_to.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

looking_for=$1
dest_dir=$2
found=$(cat)
if [ -z "$found" ]
then echo "$looking_for - file not found"
else cp "$found" "$dest_dir"
```

```
while read -r i; do
    find . -name "$i" | ./copy_to.sh "$i" /path/to/directory
done < toGet.txt
```

Comment: awesome thank you!; but I needed to add `fi` to end of the copy_to.sh script; which I could not add to your answer as 'edits need to have 6 characters' :)